# Ionic 3 capacitor Android build web not native

Tags: capacitor

I have an Ionic 3 project. Every time I build the Android app with Android Studio, Capacitor.platform returns 'web' and Capacitor.isNative returns 'false'. Therefore, the native plugins do not work. Do you know how I can fix and / or control this?

I have a Service with this code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

@Injectable()
export class PlatformProvider{
  constructor(){
    console.log("PLATAFORMA: " + Capacitor.getPlatform());
    console.log("Nativo: " + Capacitor.isNative);
  }


  public isAndroid(): boolean{
    return Capacitor.platform==='android';

  }
  public isiOS(): boolean{
    return Capacitor.platform==='ios';

  }

  public isAPP(): boolean{
    return Capacitor.isNative;
  }

}
```

LogCat from Android Studio show this

```
File: http://localhost/build/main.js - Line 10386 - Msg: PLATAFORMA: web
File: http://localhost/build/main.js - Line 10387 - Msg: Nativo: false
```

SplashScreen not work
FCM not work
and any native plugin

please, help me!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this problem?